# How can I split a string based on the character - using regex?

Tags: regex, string, split

I have multiple lines, each with a string containing an email address and other data separated by a - character.
Here is a sample.

```
a.jones@meonly.com-935567
a.smith@youonly.net-crankdev-539046
AAPets.bark@why.org-Cobbled Shoes Collective-9909
```

When I use the following regex
`^(.*?)-`
This regex returns everything after the - such as 935567.
That result is nice but the opposite of what I need.
The result I need is the email address (everything preceding the -)

I am not using C or java.

I cannot seem to craft the correct regex.This should be simple and I have performed some online searches but I am spending too much time on it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: "I am not using C or java." - what ARE you using?

Comment: That regexp should match everything *before* the `-`, not after. How are you actually using it?

Comment: If you're using it in a regexp replacement, then it matches everything before the `-`, and replaces it with whatever new string you specify. If the new string is empty, then  it leaves the number at the end.

Comment: `-.*` would be the opposite of what you have now; if you are replacing that with nothing, you are left with the email address.

Answer (score 2):

Email addresses [may contain hyphens](https://snov.io/knowledgebase/what-is-a-valid-email-address-format/#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20The%20period%20character%20(.,.com%20is%20not%20allowed).) provided they are not the first or last character of the domain (e.g., `'x@yz-.com'` and `'x@-yz.com'` are invalid, whereas `'x-@y-z.com'` is permitted). Despite these rules some service providers, including [Google and Yahoo!](https://verifalia.com/help/email-validations/can-email-addresses-have-hyphens-minus-signs-dashes) do not permit hyphens in email addresses.

The domain name has two parts separated by a period.

Since the intent is not to verify the email address we may match the following regular expression.

```
^.+@.+\.[^-]+
```

---

Matches of the following strings are indicated by the party hats.

```
a.jones@meonly.com-935567
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
a.smith@youonly.net-crankdev-539046
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AAPets.bark@why.org-Cobbled Shoes Collective-9909
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
a.sm-ith-@you-only.net-crankdev-539046
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/58ivxU/1)

---

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
^       match the beginning of the string
.+      match one or more characters other than line terminators
@       match '@'
.+      match one or more characters other than line terminators
\.      match '.'
[^-]+   match one or more characters other than '-'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
^(.*?)(?=-)
```

The matched part is in a *capture group*, depending of lib/tool/language, can be rendered as
`&`, `$&`, `\1` or `$1`

Example with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) in [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) mode:

```
$ grep -oP '^(.*?)(?=-)' file
a.jones@meonly.com
a.smith@youonly.net
AAPets.bark@why.org
```

[**Online Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/f4tpot/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | start of line |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `-` | - |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |